# Need primefaces layoutunit to behave as overlay

Tags: primefaces, primefaces-extensions

[image: click here]

Hi All,

Kindly check attached image.
I need to make the right side layoutunit to act as an overlay over center layout.
By default, when we expand right side layoutunit, center layout will gets shrinked. I want to keep the center layoutunit as static, so that when we expand right side layoutunit, it should behave as overlay over the center content.

Any suggestion would be much helpful.

[image: image link]

Answer (score 0):

Try `<p:layoutUnit collapsible="true" .../>`

Comment: Hi oleg, collapsible=true will make that layout with expand and collapse option. But my case is, when i expand the right layoutunit, the center layoutunit should not shrink/minimize its width. the right layoutunit should overlay over the center content.